# Open a d3 tree layout to show the node a user has searched for by typing request in a search box

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, highlight

I am using Mike Bostock's [tree layout](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) as the basis for a searchable tree. I am wondering if it is possible for a user to input a name into a search box and the tree to open its nodes to the named node, if it found within the tree.

```
`{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
     {
      "name": "analytics",
      "children": [
         {
          "name": "cluster",
          "children": [
             {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
             {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
             {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
             {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
           ]
         },
         {
          "name": "graph",
          "children": [
             {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
             {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
             {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
             {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
             {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
           ]
         },
         {
          "name": "optimization",
          "children": [
             {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
             ]
         }
     ]
}, ...etc`
```

So for example the nodes are all closed down, only the root node "flare" is showing on screen and the user searches for "MergeEdge" which is found as a leaf node under "cluster" which is under "analytics". The tree would then open only those nodes required to show the children of "cluster" because that is where "MergeEdge" was found. I have tried with jsonpath.js but didn't get very far and with the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133500/how-to-find-a-node-in-a-tree-with-javascript) which I was getting returns with but only when the nodes are open displaying the one I'm searching for.

I want to use different json files that may have too many nodes to display all of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code is based off the code from [example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) you linked, then this should be pretty simple.

When the page loads initially, call the `toggle` function for every node to ensure that all children are hidden. Now that all nodes except the root are hidden, you need to use the `_children` attribute of each node to find the children. Once you find the child that matches the name that is searched for, call `toggle` on it and every parent back up to the root. To re-display the graph with the toggled nodes call `update`.