# What is the time complexity of parseInt() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I found some info regarding time complexity of certain [JavaScript functions like `push`, `pop`,  `shift`, `slice` or `splice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614237/javascript-runtime-complexity-of-array-functions), but was wondering what the time complexity of `parseInt()` (or, as a bonus, `parseFloat()`)

[Number.parseInt() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt)

[Number.parseFloat() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat)

Comment: You would be hard-pressed to make it anything but O(N), with N being the length of the input string.

Comment: Just wondering why you are curious about this. In such cases normally constants and multipliers dominate the actual time taken, whether it's O(1) or O(n) or O(n2) or O(n!) or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

This is not stated explicitly in the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix), buy you may assume that it is linear by the number of characters representing the value being parsed.

Comment: Why would anyone expect it to be stated in the specification? If's a function of the implementation.

Comment: @torazaburo 1) Thank you for editing. 2) To limit possible implementations. For example, the exponential-time algorithm conforms current specification.

Comment: Minor point, but I'm not aware of any feature in the spec which is constrained in terms of O().

Comment: There are, but very few, e.g. [Section 23.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-objects) states: Map object must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are **sublinear** on the number of elements in the collection.