# Mixing Arrays using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

What's the best way to mix multiple arrays like the way in the image below,

PS:

- I don't know what will be the length of each array
- Arrays will contain +10000 elements
- There will be more than 3 arrays

I made a solution for it but I'm looking for any better solution

[image: mixing arrays]

Here's my Own solution, I was looking for any better idea

```
import { compact, flattenDeep } from "lodash/array";

export const doTheMagic = master => {
  const longest = master.reduce((p, c, i, a) => (a[p].length > c.length ? p : i), 0);
  const mixed = master[longest].map((i, k) => {
    return master.map((o, a) => {
      if (master[a][k]) return master[a][k];
    });
  });
  const flaten = flattenDeep(mixed);
  return  compact(flaten);// to remove falsey values
};
const one = [1,2,3];
const two = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
const three = ['k','l','m','n'];
const mix = doTheMagic([one,two,three]);
console.log('mix: ', mix);
```

Comment: so the arrays are arranged in random manner?

Comment: Not literally random
I want the master array to have the first element of each array, then the second then the third, etc

Comment: "Not literally random"

Comment: @epascarello Sorry I edited my reply!

Comment: You should share your solution with us

Comment: FYI: Photo of code is useless, show your solution

Comment: Hard to give a better solution without knowing your baseline solution

Comment: Ok I will post my solution

Comment: Answered, Please check my solution

Comment: Posted my solution

Comment: Your solution is `stuff here` ? :)

Comment: @JeremyThille https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877054/5092690

Comment: Edited My question guys, take a look now the length problem will not occur.

Comment: @geeksamu post your attempt inside your question, not as an answer...

Comment: @JeremyThille Done ️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use lodash for your solution.

```js
const { flow, zip, flatten, filter} = _

const doTheMagic = flow(
  zip,
  flatten,
  filter
)

const one = [1, 2, 3]
const two = ['', '', '', '', '', '']
const three = ['foo', 'bar', 'wow', 'okay']

const result = doTheMagic(one, two, three)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Works with different length of arrays and makes use of functional programming for elegant code.

Here's a codepen to run: https://codepen.io/matteodem/pen/mddQrwe

Comment: Nice I didn't know that Lodash has zip ️. Thanks for your Answer

Comment: ... or you could just write 4 lines of code and avoid loading a library :)

Comment: I just like using lodash. Of course there's a bit of overhead but that's for the OP to decide.

Comment: @JeremyThille It's okay for using Lodash I'm using it too much in my current project

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful please mark it as approved :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to achieve that, one `for loop` can make it. This will work if you don't know the number of arrays and array length as well.

```js
function doTheMagic(arr){
  let ans = [];
  let maxLength = -1;
  
  arr.forEach((tempArr)=>{
    if(tempArr.length > maxLength){
      maxLength = tempArr.length;
    }
  })
  
  let l1=0,l2=0,l3=0;
  
  for(let i=0;i<maxLength;i++){
    arr.forEach((tempArr)=>{
      if(tempArr[i]){
        ans.push(tempArr[i]);
      }
    })

  }
  return ans;
}


let a1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
let a2 = ["","","","","",""];
let a3 = ['1','2','3','4','5'];


console.log(doTheMagic([a1,a2,a3]));
```

Comment: What if I don't know the number of arrays?

Comment: Can you check my own solution I just posted it

Comment: @geeksamu I have updated my answer according to your requirement, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Own solution, I was looking for any better idea

```
import { compact, flattenDeep } from "lodash/array";

export const doTheMagic = master => {
  const longest = master.reduce((p, c, i, a) => (a[p].length > c.length ? p : i), 0);
  const mixed = master[longest].map((i, k) => {
    return master.map((o, a) => {
      if (master[a][k]) return master[a][k];
    });
  });
  const flaten = flattenDeep(mixed);
  return  compact(flaten);// to remove falsey values
};
const one = [1,2,3];
const two = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
const three = ['k','l','m','n'];
const mix = doTheMagic([one,two,three]);
console.log('mix: ', mix);
```

Comment: Check my solution, let me know if it helps

Comment: I have updated solution, it is adapted to not knowing number of arrays. let me know it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let a2 = ["", "", "", "", "", ""];
let a3 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

const doTheMagic = arrayOfArrays => {
  let maxLength = 0;
  let result = [];
  for (arr in arrayOfArrays) {
    maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, arrayOfArrays[arr].length);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arrayOfArrays.length; j++) {
      if (arrayOfArrays[j][i]) {
        result.push(arrayOfArrays[j][i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(doTheMagic([a1, a2, a3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with an unknown number of arrays, each one of unknown length :

```js
const arrays = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  ["@", "#", "?"]
];

let output = [];

while (arrays.some(a => a.length)) { // While any of the arrays still has an element in it, keep going
  for (let a of arrays) {
    if (!a.length) continue;
    output.push(a.shift()); // remove the first element of the array and add it to output
  }
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Just curious, is `shift()` O(1)?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: It means does shift operation works in constant time irrespective of input size?

Comment: Time complexity of shift mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614237/javascript-runtime-complexity-of-array-functions).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the better, but how you can write code that handles any number of arrays passed in.

```js
const weave = (...args) =>  // convert arguments to an array
  args.reduce((res, arr, offset) => {  // loop over the arrays 
    arr.forEach((v, i) => res[offset + i * args.length] = v) // loop over array and add items to their indexes
    return res
  }, []).filter(x => x !== undefined) // remove the unused indexes


const one = [1, 2, 3]
const two = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
const three = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
const result = weave(one, two, three)
console.log(result)

const result2 = weave(one, two)
console.log(result2)

const result3 = weave(one, two, three, ['*', '&'])
console.log(result3)
```