# What is wrong with my Tape-Equilibrium solutions performance for Codility

Tags: javascript, algorithm, puzzle

Here is my solution that doesn't pass the performance requirements.
As far as I can tell it is similar to other solutions I have looked up:

```
function solution(A) {
    let slice = A.slice(1,A.length);
    let firstSliceSum = A[0];
    let lastSliceSum = slice.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    let smallestValue = Math.abs(firstSliceSum-lastSliceSum);
    for(let i=1;i<A.length-1;i++){
        let shift = slice.shift();
        firstSliceSum=firstSliceSum+shift;
        lastSliceSum=lastSliceSum-shift;
        let diff = Math.abs(firstSliceSum-lastSliceSum);
        if(diff<smallestValue)smallestValue=diff;
    }
    return smallestValue;
}
```

It just has one for loop that iterates the elements, not counting the initial "reduce" function.
I have seen similar Java solutions that are supposed to pass with 100%.
Link to the challenge : https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/tape_equilibrium/

Comment: Are you able to specify what the performance requirements are?

Comment: Not a javascript expert, but shift() seems to have O(n) complexity, so maybe worth replacing this with `let shift = A[i];`.

Comment: @SaiBot yes seems that shift() was the main issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues here.

- As pointed out, you are using `shift()` inside a loop [which has a time complexity of O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614237/javascript-runtime-complexity-of-array-functions). ultimately making your code O(n<sup>2</sup>).
- Second, you are considering the first index `0` sum as well whereas the constraints mentioned say for any 0 < `P` < N.

Quoting from the problem statement mentioned there:

> Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two
>   non-empty parts: A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ...,
>   A[N − 1].

- So you will have to calculate from `1` till `A.length-1`.

**Snippet:**

```js
function solution(A) {
  let slice = A.slice(1, A.length);
  let firstSliceSum = A[0];
  let lastSliceSum = slice.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  let smallestValue = -1;
  for (let i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
    let diff = Math.abs(firstSliceSum - lastSliceSum);
    if (smallestValue == -1 || diff < smallestValue) smallestValue = diff;
    firstSliceSum += A[i];
    lastSliceSum -= A[i];
  }
  return smallestValue;
}

console.log(solution([3, 1, 2, 4, 3]));
```

- In the above(correct code), we initialize the `smallestValue` to `-1` as absolute value can't go negative.
- In the loop, we avoid `.shift()` and just take the differences of `firstSliceSum` and `lastSliceSum`.
- Later, we reduce `A[i]` from `lastSliceSum` and add it to `firstSliceSum` as we need to consider `A[i]` for next upcoming split and remove it from right part of the split.

Comment: Thank you this is really thorough answer and explains everything!

Comment: @somerandomusername Glad to help :)