# traverse from a specific point in json object and up to find all parents

Tags: javascript, json

I got a json object like this

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "A",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "B",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "C",
          "nodes": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I have as input the id of the object, lets take id: 3, how would I scan the whole three find the object with specific id and then scan upwards to the last parent.

So after the scan is done I know that C has parent B and B has parent A, so I can then print that like A-B-C

all based on me knowing the id of object I want to find parents of.

The above object can be of any lenght and can have many nodes and levels. So anyone has any idea how to traverse up the levels to top level if starting at specific level?

edit:

when I try to parse this

```
let data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "testing": "something",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "name",
        "testing": "something",
        "nodes": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name",
    "testing": "something",
    "nodes": []
  }
]
```

to json object by doing JSON.parse(data) I get an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Also tried this

```
      let jsonObject = JSON.stringify($scope.data);
      jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
      createTree(jsonObject, null, nodeData.id)
```

and get different error:

```
TypeError: obj.nodes is not iterable
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes add that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a node in a tree with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133500/how-to-find-a-node-in-a-tree-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Do a basic DFS scan, add `parent` property along the way, and climb up when node found.

```js
let jsonParsed = JSON.parse(`
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "A",
 "nodes": [
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "B",
   "nodes": [
    {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "C",
     "nodes": []
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
`)

let arr = []

function climbTree(obj) {
 arr.unshift(obj.name)
 if (obj.parent) {
  climbTree(obj.parent)
 }
}

function createTree(obj, parent = null, targetId = null) {
 obj.parent = parent
 if (targetId === obj.id) {
  return climbTree(obj)
 }
 for (let node of obj.nodes) {
  createTree(node, obj, targetId)
 }
}

createTree(jsonParsed, null, 3)

console.log(arr.join('-'))
```

Comment: I get an error parsing the json to jsonParsed object. see my updated question to see where i get stuck