# Search Data in the Nested Tree View (Or Nested JSON Object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to implement a search in a Treeview which renders a list of nested Data. I am using Material UI to add the UI code for this and need to add a function which can search through the nested JSON objects and return the parsed nested JSON only.

My Data -

```
const TreeViewData = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Documents',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Report',
      children: [
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'PDF',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Files',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Excel',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      name: 'Programs',
      children: [
        {
          id: '6',
          name: 'Codes',
        },
        {
          id: '7',
          name: 'Data',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I need to add a function like `onSearch(text)` so that when user inputs any search text he will see the reduced tree view with parsed data.

For example -

`onSearch(R)` should return

```
const TreeViewData = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Documents',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Report',
      children: [
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'PDF',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      name: 'Programs',
      children: [
        {
          id: '6',
          name: 'Codes',
        },
        {
          id: '7',
          name: 'Data',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

again `onSearch(excel)` returns

```
const TreeViewData = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Documents',
  children: [
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Files',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Excel',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Note - Tried with Lodash too but that didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could search into the tree structure by using recursion. 
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133500/how-to-find-a-node-in-a-tree-with-javascript)

Comment: That did not work as I need the desired output mentioned above in my question.