# how to search the node value with id from a parent-child json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a parent-child json based data

```
[
   {
      "_id":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06",
      "name":"11111",
      "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
      "children":[
         {
            "_id":"624015c369f627d1d3484b0b",
            "name":"222222",
            "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
            "children":[
               
            ],
            "parent":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06",
            "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015c369f627d1d3484b0b",
            "__v":0
         },
         {
            "_id":"624015d069f627d1d3484b10",
            "name":"333333",
            "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
            "children":[
               {
                  "_id":"6240161269f627d1d3484b15",
                  "name":"444444",
                  "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "_id":"624021be69f627d1d3484b1f",
                        "name":"5555555",
                        "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
                        "children":[
                           {
                              "_id":"624021cc69f627d1d3484b24",
                              "name":"555551111",
                              "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "parent":"624021be69f627d1d3484b1f",
                              "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015d069f627d1d3484b10,6240161269f627d1d3484b15,624021be69f627d1d3484b1f,624021cc69f627d1d3484b24",
                              "__v":0
                           },
                           {
                              "_id":"624021d569f627d1d3484b29",
                              "name":"555552222",
                              "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "parent":"624021be69f627d1d3484b1f",
                              "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015d069f627d1d3484b10,6240161269f627d1d3484b15,624021be69f627d1d3484b1f,624021d569f627d1d3484b29",
                              "__v":0
                           },
                           {
                              "_id":"624021de69f627d1d3484b2e",
                              "name":"555553333",
                              "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "parent":"624021be69f627d1d3484b1f",
                              "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015d069f627d1d3484b10,6240161269f627d1d3484b15,624021be69f627d1d3484b1f,624021de69f627d1d3484b2e",
                              "__v":0
                           },
                           {
                              "_id":"624021eb69f627d1d3484b33",
                              "name":"555554444",
                              "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "parent":"624021be69f627d1d3484b1f",
                              "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015d069f627d1d3484b10,6240161269f627d1d3484b15,624021be69f627d1d3484b1f,624021eb69f627d1d3484b33",
                              "__v":0
                           },
                           {
                              "_id":"624021f469f627d1d3484b38",
                              "name":"555555555",
                              "created":"2022-03-27T07:36:50.492Z",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "parent":"624021be69f627d1d3484b1f",
                              "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015d069f627d1d3484b10,6240161269f627d1d3484b15,624021be69f627d1d3484b1f,624021f469f627d1d3484b38",
                              "__v":0
                           }
                        ],
                        "parent":"6240161269f627d1d3484b15",
                        "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015d069f627d1d3484b10,6240161269f627d1d3484b15,624021be69f627d1d3484b1f",
                        "__v":0
                     }
                  ],
                  "parent":"624015d069f627d1d3484b10",
                  "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015d069f627d1d3484b10,6240161269f627d1d3484b15",
                  "__v":0
               }
            ],
            "parent":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06",
            "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06,624015d069f627d1d3484b10",
            "__v":0
         }
      ],
      "parent":null,
      "path":"624015bb69f627d1d3484b06",
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

i want to search the end leaf node by searching its _id value, for example I want to find the leaf node whose id is '624021f469f627d1d3484b38', it should output the whole node value whose name is '55555555',

I have tried the following methods.

```
const find = (array, id) => {
    var result;
    array.some(o => result = o._id === id ? o : find(o.children || [], id));
    return result;
};


const findChildById = (arr, id) => {
  const result = arr.find(o => o._id === id)
  if (result) return result
  for (const cm of arr) {
    const result = cm.children.find(o => o._id === id)
    if (result) return result
  }
}

      let node = find( nodeData, '624021f469f627d1d3484b38');
      let node =  findChildById( nodeData, '624021f469f627d1d3484b38');
```

but both methods output the undefined,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a node in a tree with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133500/how-to-find-a-node-in-a-tree-with-javascript)

Comment: Can you posted json you want to get for  id='624021f469f627d1d3484b38', pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const findChildren = (arrElement, matchingID) => {
  if (arrElement._id === matchingID) {
    return arrElement;
  } else if (arrElement.children.length) {
    let children = null;
    arrElement.children.forEach(element => {
      children = findChildren(element, matchingID);
    });
    return children;
  }
  return null;
};

console.log(findChildren(arrayChildren[0], '624021f469f627d1d3484b38'));
```